# I'm using Cisco Packet Tracer for Simulation and got error "ip address overlaps with..etc"

Tags: ip-address, subnet

The 1st row is for my router and the 2nd row is for my LAN. What's wrong? Is my IP addressing and subnetting wrong? I already checked my configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your addressing is indeed wrong :-(

First entry is correct, but second is fundamentally wrong. Prefix and mask is ok, but network and range is not. You cannot have a network `.4` with  a prefix of 27.

27 prefix says -  27 most significant bits of address specifies network. Rest of 32 bits is filled with 0. So last octet must be: 
xxx00000. When you entered your second ip address, router calculated network address for it (cleared last 5 bits) to be 192.168.1.0, which is the same as your first network, hence 'overlapping' error.

Comment: thank you sir for the reply i'm still very new to this topic and for me it is just too hard to understand yet but i'm not giving up ;) so can you suggest me sites/resources that i can review about this topic, or the best practices for ip address of wan and lan! and i only derived that IPs with my own perception since for the 1st row thats for my wan w/ 2 usable ip's is enough and for my lan i got 30 host so i just continue it...because i think will not waste any ip's am i right? LOL

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) should get you started.

Comment: Also: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could have done it the other way: `192.168.1.0/27` and `192.168.1.32/30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(2)

DHCP Activeren bij WS12

(3/4)

RT01>en
RT01#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
RT01(config)#int s0/0/0
RT01(config-if)#ip add 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.252
RT01(config-if)#no shut

RT02>en
RT02#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
RT02(config)#int s0/0/0
RT02(config-if)#ip add 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.252
RT02(config-if)#no shut


RT02>en
RT02#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
RT02(config)#route rip
RT02(config-router)#version 2
RT02(config-router)#network 192.168.95.0
RT02(config-router)#network 10.10.10.0
RT02(config-router)#do wr
Building configuration...
[OK]
RT02(config-router)#


RT01>en
RT01#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
RT01(config)#route rip
RT01(config-router)#version 2
RT01(config-router)#network 172.17.1.0
RT01(config-router)#network 10.10.10.0
RT01(config-router)#do wr
Building configuration...
[OK]
RT01(config-router)#

(5)

Ping Prnwh
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.