# Error IP Address Overlaps with...etc

Tags: networking, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm using Cisco Packet Tracer for Simulation and got error “ip address overlaps with..etc”](https://superuser.com/questions/460220/im-using-cisco-packet-tracer-for-simulation-and-got-error-ip-address-overlaps)

[image]

The 1st row is for my router and the 2nd row is for my lan whats wrong?

Is my IP addressing and subnetting is wrong? I already checked my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overlap IP ranges like that on a "multihomed" device (such as a router).

You need either an "unnumbered" link on the WAN port of the router (which can then steal one of the internal addresses), or for the addresses to be non-overlapping.

Comment: so my ip addressing and subnetting is wrong sir? thanks 4 your reply ;)

Comment: ow im very sorry is there i forum site that is related to my topic?